Notation for Organ Registration in Bach/Árpád Kommt Ihr Töchter
Could you help me with the organ notation for moving the hands up and down between keyboards? (And what's the proper term for that?)
In particular what's confusing me:

Do the square brackets missing the top or the bottom mean anything in particular? Or all square brackets have all the same meaning regardless? (In #5 below I point to a place where a variety is used)
At the first red arrow: bracket on top staff, but Pos appears in between hands and between feet and hands; which hand(s) do I need to move to Pos.? My interpretation is move right hand to Pos.
In the same place Grunds 8' 4' appears twice, yet I haven't used Pos. before and it already has Flutes 8' 4' given as registration at start. Is Grundst just redundant information since Flutes are considered Grunds anyway? And is the last Grunds supposed to apply to the system below or the system above?
Bar 13: I interpreted the first Pos. I mentioned at #2 as applying to the right hand, but now I'm told move the left hand to Hw., am I missing something? (I have skipped some parts of the music, but none of the skipped ones had any registration indications)
Last system: As I mentioned in #1, there's a variety of square brackets, some missing the top, others the bottom, others normal. Particularly confusing is where I've marked with the two red arrows, Hw. on the right hand staff, but bracket on left hand staff; to which does it apply?

Performance advice questions:

I have a 2-manual organ (so no Pos.) Do you have any advice about how you'd apply this registration to that?
I'd love to put a pp < f on the note in the blue box in the second system (i.e. fade from nothing); I can kind of play it with my pinky on the swell; but I'd have to drop middle voices (maybe not a big deal) but more importantly, I can't really play the entire line on the swell, until the trill in the next bar at least. Do you have any advice? Move back to Hw. after that one note perhaps?


[...]

[...]


I think it’s probably a good idea to split this into two separate questions: one about the notation (points 1. though 5.), and another about the performance practice (6. & 7.).

@ElementsInSpace I thought about that (I've been suggested this sort of stuff many times before on stack exchange sites), but I thought if someone has looked enough at the score to answer all the notation questions, it might just be easier for everyone to have a think at the performance. But yeah, if no one responds to the performance part I might make a separate question; it's a bit of an "if you're already here" addendum. Thanks! :)

Before providing specific answers (second section below), I think it's useful to say something general about performing a transcription / arrangement for organ.

General remarks on performing a transcription / arrangement
The performance of an organ transcription, especially when it's a reduction of a piece with complex scoring such as the Overture from Bach's St. Matthew Passion (scored for 2 string sections + flutes + oboes, basso continuo, 2 choirs, and 1 children descant), should largely be at the discretion of the performer and the available organ (and its available registration).  Organists are known for their flexibility given the frequent limitations of the physical organs at their disposal.  In this case, we are fortunate that the arranger himself (Miklós Árpás) performed his transcription in this YouTube video (!) so we can better know his intention and see illustrations of an organist's ingenuity.
Without directly answering your questions, hopefully these general guidelines that I use when preparing to play a transcription can be helpful:

First, identify the places within the transcription you want to produce the contrasting colors that the arranger chooses to highlight in the reduction while comparing it with the original scoring (heard in this performance).  Pertinent factors:

the two choirs' question and response need to be on separate manuals, thus the change of manuals for the left hand in mm. 17-18 is imperative, also at 2:18, etc.
the children choir's descant needs to be heard high and loud, so necessitating a separate manual (such as at 2:39), even if you have to play both the strings and the adult choirs using one hand on the other manual.


Feel free to develop your own scheme on maximizing the use of your available resources to implement the plan in #1:

Árpás has 3 manuals at his disposal (as opposed to your 2 manuals)  but he uses the Swell manual mostly to add stops to the Great and Positive manuals (via couplers), although in 3:18 he plays solely on the Swell when only the strings is playing.  But in the beginning where only the strings is playing too, he plays on the Great.  Throughout the piece you can see that there is no consistent manual for a certain part (i.e. strings, flute/oboe, choir 1, or choir 2); the only consistent manual seems to be the Great for the descant and the pedal for the bass.  Therefore, manual assignment and registration marking in the transcription is relative to the context and should be interpreted only to guide us to know the arranger's intention, not something we have to meticulously adhere to.

Notice how Árpás uses the Crescendo pedal at 1:40 and again at 1:56 and 2:05 to add stops for more 4' and 2' register.  Your organ may not have it (where you need to use pistons), or if your organ is digital the Crescendo pedal may be programmable (lucky you).

Starting in a new section at 4:55 (5:05 in the orchestral video), where there are quick alternations between the 3 parties (strings and the 2 choirs), Árpás changes the registration for the 3 manuals to reflect the changing mood as well as to highlight the 3 colors mimicking the effect of the original scoring.  He also uses the Crescendo pedal in alternating two significantly different levels to assist him.

The sound environment of Árpás's performance has a very long reverb (at least 5 seconds).  One technique to avoid muddy sound is to add Mixtures to highlight certain voice by emphasizing the upper harmonics.  Or you can add Reed stop(s) that blend well with the Flute / Foundation stops.


Seeing how he plays from memory and how free he is in adding/removing stops, I have a feeling that he doesn't use the same registration every time, especially with a different organ in a "dryer" space.  So, be creative and attentive to the resulting sound in order to bring out the voices better.

Organists have the privilege to do tricks:

playing the top melody on the thumb (for LH) or pinky (for RH) in a different manual (see Árpás doing this for the entire descant part at 5:48-5:56), or
playing the thumb in a different manual to help with the harmony (see Árpás doing this at 5:26), or
playing two notes with your two feet (see Árpás playing the bass in octaves toward the end starting at 7:41, ending in 7:50 with a 12th interval)

Or sometimes you have to drop middle voices.  Since it is a transcription, feel free to do what makes sense by preserving the intent of both Bach and the arranger to achieve the best artistic rendition of this great work.


Answering your specific questions
Now that I watched closely the video and matched it with your screenshots, the full score, as well as the organ specification,  I can now answer your specific questions:

The meaning of "open-top" or "open-bottom" brackets is obvious in this case, which is a helpful direction for which manual each hand needs to play, especially in a complex transcription like this.  Remember that the convention for organ score is that the first staff is always right hand, and second staff is always left hand.

In measure 9 that he's separating the full Hauptwerk "voice" in the preceding 8 measures (to be continued on the first staff only), from the new Positive "voice" that is less full than the Hauptwerk voice.
In measure 13, the "open-top" bracket is to re-unify the first two staves to be played on Hauptwerk.  It's open top so it doesn't clutter the first staff.
In measure 17 on the 2nd staff, it's to re-unify both staves to be played on the Positive.
In measure 17 on the 1st staff just before the 4th beat, I think it's a engraving mistake (should be removed).
In measure 18 on the 2nd staff, the "open-bottom" bracket is to tell you that the 2nd staff is now to be played on Hauptwerk, just like the one chord on measure 17 2nd beat.


No.  The convention is that first staff is always right hand, and second staff is always left hand.  Manual notation is to indicate which manual your hand is playing.  Thus, at your red arrow on measure 9, your left hand plays the notes of the 2nd staff on the Positive while the right hand remains playing the notes of the 1st staff on Hauptwerk.

Probably redundant, since the Positive manual has not been used.  As in my general point #2, choose the registration that works best for your organ; this is just a suggestion.  About why it's notated twice, I think it's a mistake.  I would remove the registration notation above the 3rd (pedal) staff and move the one below the pedal staff to above the 2nd staff.

On measure 13, the pick up before the 3rd beat, your left hand is supposed to join your right hand on Hauptwerk.

See #1

See my general notes #1 and #2

If you want to isolate the top note on staff 1 (which is Violin 1 in the full score) to be played on Swell, that's a great idea.  What you can do is to make your left hand play the bottom notes of staff 1 together with staff 2, but in places where it's too hard, your right thumb can help out on the Hauptwerk, a common organist trick I described in my general point # 3 (which Miklós Árpás also does).



Thank you so much for your very helpful and thorough answer! So I guess an open bracket, when it has no label, means "keep on the same keyboard" like in m.9, that really threw me off. Thanks for sharing the video, that will be really helpful for the rest of the piece as well!
And thanks for all of the performance suggestions -- I'm actually preparing a performance with 3 singers (one for each choir), so I'll try to get more of the orchestra parts in, but I want to start with this transcription as a basis. Thanks again! :)

So I guess the couplers are not notated in the score? Now that I'm watching the video carefully I'm noticing that...

@Gabi "I guess the couplers are not notated in the score?"  Apparently not in the beginning of this score, although usually organ scores DO include couplers notation in the initial registration.  And I also noticed that "Hw. to Pos." notation on measure 17 is a typo; I think he meant "Pos to Hw".  I have never seen organs having "Hw. to Pos." coupler and it's not in the spec.  But when I see the video (starting at 1:30), he didn't even use Pos to HW (!) since the Positive keys of this tracker organ were not depressed when he plays on Hw.

@Gabi "I'm actually preparing a performance with 3 singers"  Sounds exciting!  Best wishes for your project, hopefully you'll contribute your own arrangement (for 2 manual organ, and as accompaniment to 3 singers) in "social score" site such as MuseScore for others to benefit.

@Gabi BTW, despite the typos on the score, I'm glad I refrained from doubting the arrangement quality, because the video shows he IS a very versatile & artistic organist.  Also, it turns out his expertise and experience has been doing all kinds of arrangements (7 volumes published).  See this article (use Google translate for English).

@Gabi "I guess an open bracket, when it has no label, means 'keep on the same keyboard'"  I'm not sure I would put it that way.  I think it would have been more helpful if the bracket on the m. 9 1st staff is replaced with a "bottom open" bracket on the 2nd staff, enclosing the "Pos" manual marking.  This would be more consistent with the rest of the manual markings.  I would instead characterize brackets (whether open or closed) as "grouping the manual marking with the notes on that manual".

Yeah, having the video as well with the score helps a lot of things: couplers, keyboards, stop changes -- that was a great idea! :) And yeah, if I end up writing an arrangement, I can share it, that's a great idea, though so far I just reduced a MusicXML of the full score I found to have only 3 voices; I was planning to write a transcription myself, but getting 5-6 voices on the hands staves is a nightmare from a notation software perspective; but if I end up writing rather than just making notes on the score I will share it.

I do have some qualms with his transcription; a really big one is that he changes some notes, so I'm at the point where I wanted to write down the instrumental cues for the singers' score, and the bar before a couple of entrances, the transcription has a different melody than the full score; so for now I left blank, and will commit to something once I learn it; it'll probably take me 1-2 months to learn it, as I'm not that advanced and am in church only 2-3 days/week anyway. Thanks again for all the help and good wishes! :)
